# how setup react.js on symfony project using webpack encore?

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack

I have a symfony project which symfony version is 2.7.7 and I want to add a reactjs template, I had following the setps in documentation but I don't know when I should add webpack encore configuration to enable react because the project has already webpack configuration.

the current **webpack.config.js** looks like:

```
const path = require('path')
const colors = require('colors/safe')
const scriptPath = './vendor/../distribution/main/core/Resources/scripts/lib'
const collectPackages = require(path.resolve(scriptPath, 'collect-packages'))
const buildConfig = require(path.resolve(scriptPath, 'webpack'))

const isWatchMode = process.argv.indexOf('--i-tgt=watch') !== -1
const config = buildConfig(__dirname, collectPackages(__dirname), isWatchMode)

console.log(colors.yellow(JSON.stringify(config._debug, null, 2) + '\n'))

module.exports = config;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: symfony/webpack-encore-bundle need symfony 3.4, webpack.config.js should be like: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/installation.html#creating-the-webpack-config-js-file

Comment: @AndreaManzi the symfony version for my project is 2, so what I'm looking for is how to setup reactjs but I don't find any documentation about it or how to do this with this version